# How to open files inside multiple folders with a tree view?

Tags: c#, treeview, directory, text-files

I have recently gotten into programming and I have been working designing my first program. It's designed to store and create notes inside a folder, but I'm having an issue with opening the txt files that are inside other folders besides the first folder in my tree view. I've been trying to work it out for about a week now but have been unable to figure out a solution. What did I miss in my programming?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace InfoHub
{
    public partial class InfoHome : Form
    {
        public InfoHome()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void InfoHome_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            //puts info on the top all windows
            this.TopMost = true;

        }
        //this string path makes it possiable for "C:\\Users\\epoch\\Desktop\\InfoHub"
        //to be used in button2_Click
        string path = "C:\\Users\\epoch\\Desktop\\InfoHub";
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ListDirectory(treeView1, "C:\\Users\\epoch\\Desktop\\InfoHub"); 
        }
            // this is the Directory Structure
            private void ListDirectory(TreeView treeView, string path)
            {
                treeView.Nodes.Clear();
                var rootDirectoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);

                treeView.Nodes.Add(CreateDirectoryNode(rootDirectoryInfo));

            }

            private static TreeNode CreateDirectoryNode(DirectoryInfo directoryInfo)
            {
                var directoryNode = new TreeNode(directoryInfo.Name);
                foreach (var directory in directoryInfo.GetDirectories())
                    directoryNode.Nodes.Add(CreateDirectoryNode(directory));

                foreach (var file in directoryInfo.GetFiles())
                    directoryNode.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(file.Name));

                return directoryNode;
            }

        //this button click opens programs
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string TreeNodeName = treeView1.SelectedNode.ToString().Replace("TreeNode: ",string.Empty);

            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(path + "\\" + TreeNodeName);
        }

        //this opens the notpad 
        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Process.Start("notepad.exe");
        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            folderCreator newform = new folderCreator();
            newform.ShowDialog();
        }

        private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the name of node is either the name of the directory or file, `TreeNode.FullPath` will represent the relative path to the file. You can combine that with the base `path` to get the full path:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // "InfoHub" will appear twice below, GetParent removes one of them.
    var fullPath = Path.Combine(
        Directory.GetParent(path).FullName,
        treeView1.SelectedNode.FullPath
    );

    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(fullPath);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm going to be using this program for studying so this helps a lot!